# How do I convert CSS radial gradient to Flutter

Tags: css, flutter

How do I convert this CSS radial gradient to Flutter gradient:

background: radial-gradient(50% 50% at 50% 50%, #1AD4FD 0%, #2588FD 100%);

[Gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTKzl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough equivalent :

```
Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        gradient: RadialGradient(
          colors: [
            Color(0xFF1AD4FD),
            Color(0xFF2588FD)
          ]
        )
      ),
      width: 320, 
      height: 180,
    )
```